# Checkboxes in form, change URL encoding method?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, checkbox, url-encoding

I have a form that uses GET method and submits to a different page. The form consists of checkboxes that the user can select multiple values. For example, the checkboxes have a name of school_facilities[]

When the user submits, the form is correctly adding ?school_facilities[]=foo&school_facilities[]=bar however, for the results to display correctly on the results page, the URL needs to be ?school_facilities=foo-,-bar instead. How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Munge the data on the server instead. It's simpler and reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onclick of the submit button of the form populate the array checked value to a hidden field :-

```
<input type="hidden" name="school_facilities" id="school_facilities" />

<input type=checkbox name=checkboxes[] class=popVal />

<script>//jquery library</script>

$(".popVal").click(function(){
var values = new Array();
$.each($("input[name='checkboxes[]']:checked"), function() {
  values.push($(this).val());
});

alert(values); // this will be comma separated values
$("#school_facilities").val(values); 
});
```

Then post the form.

Comment: this is perfect! The only thing, I need to add a dash "-" before and after the comma, so it looks like this: ?school_facilities=foo-,-bar

Comment: That you can do in php after getting the school_facilities var like this:- str_replace(",", "-,-", $_GET['school_facilities']);